# Google Chrome dev tools do not display website on developer machine (when Remote Debugging Android Device)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Following the [instructions here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/), I can see my Android device in Chrome on my developer machine in `Chrome > DevTools > Main Menu > More tools > Remote devices`.

I can see the website that the Android device has open. If I click Inspect, a new Chrome window opens on my developer machine, and I see the mobile width browser window open with Developer Tools on the right.

However, the website loaded on my Android device will not load in this window. I see a white screen. I click Reload, and the loading progress bar will display, but then I receive a white screen again.

I make sure the Android device screen is unlocked, repeat the process above, but I always end up with a white screen.

How do I fix this please?

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a screenshot of the popup window that you are seeing. Do you see the frame of the mobile in it? Is there any error in the console log? If you scroll or interact with the white screen, do you see the changes in your mobile?